# Error: No such file or directory: i want to use heading names from excel sheet to create tkinter drop down

Tags: pandas, tkinter

```py
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
    
def main():

    df1= pd.read_excel (excel_filepath,"Sheet") ## here i am reading the file ##
    df2= pd.read_excel (excel_filepath1,"Sheet2") 
    df= pd.read_excel (excel_filepath2,"Sheet1")

return

    r=tk.Tk()
    r.title('')
    text1 = tk.Label(r, text="Enter File path of the INPUT AND EXP Excel file: ")
    text1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    excel_filepath = tk.StringVar()
        
     
    df1= pd.read_excel (str(excel_filepath.get()),"Sheet")## this is the line showing error ##
        
    heading1=list((df1.columns.values)) ## this is the line reading readings ##
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. You are passing an invalid path. What have you done to debug this? Hae you printed out `str(excel_filepath.get())` to see if it's what you think it should be? In one place you use `excel_filepath` as if it were a string. At another time you're using it as if it's an object with the `get` method.

Comment: You can use a print statement to print out the value. However, based on the code in the question it seems pretty clear you're using the value from the entry widget about a millisecond after creating the `excel_filepath`  variable. The user won't have had time to see the widget, much less type in it.

Comment: Hey Bryan thanks for your help i tried printing out the excel_filepath using  str(excel_filepath.get()) but is showing error stringVar object is not callable

Comment: Is there any way to call stringVar in tkinter loop so that it does not pop up  error? ""stringVar object is not callable'

Comment: The line used to work perfectly when i used the fixed directory i.e  df1=pd.read_excel("my_file.xlsx",sheet1) but when i try to use excel_filepath it is showing that error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Load button. When clicked, it will read the columns and will update the drop down:

```
def Load_excel_data():
    enter code here`df1= pd.read_excel(excel_filename)
    heading1=list((df1.columns.values))
```